# ValueError: Cannot assign "''": "" must be a "" instance. error

Tags: django-models, foreign-keys

I am trying to create an object and assigning a foreign-key from an input field but i am getting a bizarre error, i have tried to assign it using the id, the name but nothing seems to work, any help will be much appreciated.
This is the model :

```
class Node(MPTTModel):
    parent              = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')
    name                = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

This is the form field :

```
<input  type="hidden" name="parent" value="{{ current_tree }}" />
```

This is the view :

```
get_node_parent = request.POST.get('parent', '').strip()

Node.objects.create(parent=get_node_parent)
```

Every time i try to create the model i have the message that it must be a Node instance.

Comment: Why is that a bizarre error? A `parent` should be `Node` (since it is a fk to `Node`), so why do you expect to use a string?

Comment: Hey Willem, I am not using a string the output of the 'get_node_parent' is a node in fact so i don't understand why i am having this error.

Comment: But `POST` is in essence a dictionary that maps strings to strings, so `get_node_parent` is a string.

Comment: i think that i am missing something here, do you have any idea how can i achieve what i am trying to do since am new to django and i have difficulties to make it working.

Comment: exactly what is `{{ current_tree }}`, the name of your `Node`? It's primary key?

Comment: {{ current_tree }} yes sir it is the name of the Node, I have tried also the pk and the id but i have always the same error.

Comment: and you are sure you make a POST request?

Comment: yes i have printed the output of 'get_node_parent' and i got the exact input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Node` constructor expects a `Node` object as parent. Since your `parent` contains the `.name` field of that `Node`, you thus first need to fetch that node, like:

```
parent_name = request.POST.get('parent')

node_parent = None
if parent_name is not None:
    node_parent = Node.objects.get(name=parent_name)

Node.objects.create(parent=node_parent)
```

We thus first retrieve the value for `'parent'`. If such value exists, we thus fetch the given `Node` for that name with `Node.objects.get(name=...)`. Then we can create the new `Node` with the given `name`.

Note that you probably want to set a name as well, and make the `name` field `unique=True`, since otherwise using a `name` will not be sufficient to "identify" the `Node` object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is exactly what i was missing. Otherwise i have queried the node_parent using the id so i will not have to set the name to unique true.